# Show a measure is invariant under all translations by using compositions of reflections

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> $f_x: (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ by
>   $f_x(y)=2x-y$ and where $\mathcal{B}$ is the borel sigma-algebra
>
> Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathcal{B}$ which is invariant under al
>   reflections: $\mu(B)=\mu(f_x(B))$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$
>   and $B\in\mathcal{B}$.  Furthermore suppose that $\mu([0,1])=k <
>  \infty$.  Show, by using compositions of reflections, that $\mu$ is
>   invariant under all translations and deduce that $\mu=k\lambda$ where
>   $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure.

I have really no idea how I can do this. First, I don't see how I can use reflections to show something about all translations.

I think it need to be something like: $\mu$(compositions of reflections of a set E) = $\mu(E)$. But I don't know which compositions of reflections I need to use and how it is possible to prove something about all translations with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a basic fact that any translation is a composition of two reflections. Let's see what happens when we compose two reflections, say $f_x$ and $f_y$:
$$
f_x(f_y(a)) = f_x(2y - a) = 2x - (2y - a) = a + (2x - 2y).
$$
Voilà -- a translation by $2x - 2y$. By choosing $x$ and $y$ appropriately, we can get any translation we want.

That means if the measure is invariant under reflection, it is also invariant under translation. The hypothesis that $\mu([0,1]) = k < \infty$ is only necessary for the latter part, to show that $\mu = k \lambda$.

Comment: The hypothesis is necessary to show $\mu = k\lambda$

Comment: @Gono I was just thinking that was probably it. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so to prove $\mu$ is invariant under all translations, I can say:

I define $ A:=f_y(B)$, 

$\mu(f_x(f_y(B)))= \mu(f_x(A)) = \mu(A)$ (because $\mu$ is invariant onder all reflections) $= \mu(f_y(B))= \mu(B)$.

But then I need to be sure that if $B \in \mathcal{B}$, also $f_x(B) \in \mathcal{B}$, otherwise it don't work.

Comment: Ah, we want a translation over a set $B \in \mathcal{B}$ and some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. So $\mu(B+c)= \mu(f_{\frac{1}{2}c}(f_0(B)))=\mu(B)$

Comment: @MathMe The Borel sigma-algebra is preserved under translations, reflections, etc. (so $f_x(B) \in \mathcal{B}$). Anyway, yes, your second comment is right.